# I'm trying to style divs in a grid created by a js function (pixel art editor)

Tags: javascript, dom

Trying to create a pixel art editor.
The goal is to shade in a div on hover or onclick.
I'd like to make a separate function so the user can pick a color.
The div's were made with the following function.

I tried storing the divs after they were created into a variable.
I tried making a function that selects the divs by class name and running it after the function to create them is run.

```
function createGrid(y){
  let container = document.querySelector('.container');
  for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';
    for(x = 1; x <= y; x++){
      let cell = document.createElement('div');
      cell.className = 'cell';
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    container.appendChild(row);
  }
}

//I notice other people doing this but I don't understand how this makes a 
//grid.
//what do the $ mean and why 960/x?

function createGrid(x) {
    for (var rows = 0; rows < x; rows++) {
        for (var columns = 0; columns < x; columns++) {
            $("#container").append("<div class='grid'></div>");
        };
    };
    $(".grid").width(960/x);
    $(".grid").height(960/x);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just append a css class with a `:hover` option where you do your shading instead. But if you HAVE to do it on JS, you can use the `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` functions like so:

```
function createGrid(y){
  let container = document.querySelector('.container');
  for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';
    for(x = 1; x <= y; x++){
      let cell = document.createElement('div');
      cell.className = 'cell';
      cell.onmouseenter = () => cell.setAttribute("style", "background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2)")
      cell.onmouseleave = () => cell.setAttribute("style", "")
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    container.appendChild(row);
  }
}
```

[Here's a working example](https://jsbin.com/xuvojuvera/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I'm trying to make a pixel editor so being able to set the on hover or on click color in a separate function is needed. Sorry for not specifying that, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Matthew.Mustard In that case, consider using `cell.setAttribute("class", "myClassWithHoverOptions")` instead. You can add a 3rd line with the event `onclick` if you want to add another class for when you click on a cell